# Post commit update returns "Skipped '.'" with non-serveradmin user

Tags: linux, svn, permissions, mediatemple, post-commit-hook

I have a post-commit hook that cds into my website's directory and runs svn update. For my serveradmin, it works correctly. For other users, the commit works and the hook executes, but the update returns "Skipped '.'" to the log file.

Here's as much pertinent information as I can think of:

- It's a Linux environment on a Media Temple gridserver (gs)
- The repository was set up in /home/XXXXX/data/svn/reponame
- The working copy was checked out into /home/XXXXX/domains/mydomain.com/projectname
- serveradmin and otheruser both belong to the same group (we'll call it usergroup)
- all files involved have ownership of serveradmin.usergroup

  all working copy files (including .svn files) have rwx permissions for user and group

  all files in the hooks directory have rwx group permissions for user and group

  each user checks out the repo via svn+ssh, and I validated that the commit hook is executing as the user who is doing the commit (not apache or svnserve)

Comment: I'm starting to suspect that this a limitation with Media Temple. A non-serveradmin user only has access to its home directory. So since the commit hook executes as whichever user does the commit, it fails to cd into the right directory and then the update subsequently fails since there's no working copy where it is. Leaving this open for a a couple days in case someone has a workaround for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tying up this old question since, as I mentioned in my comment before, this ended up being a limitation with Media Temple and their support team confirmed that there is no workaround.